# want snowsql to list all history query which are causing high credit quota usage from WH and RM

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

want snowsql to list all history queries which are causing high credit quota usage from a particular one WH and single RM.

I know I can use the filter in snow sight UI but I do not see all my requirements being fulfilled with the available filters.

any help on preparing snowsql?

Comment: Just run a query against the QUERY_HISTORY view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```sql
select total_elapsed_time, user_name, role_name, warehouse_name, warehouse_size, query_text
from table(information_schema.query_history(dateadd('days',-1,current_timestamp()),current_timestamp()))
where total_elapsed_time > 2000
order by total_elapsed_time desc;
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/query_history